# Spring Social Facebook dependency issue

Tags: facebook, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

I am trying to connect my application with facebook. I copied the code from

http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-facebook/

Added all the stated dependencies but the error doesn't seem to go. Code given below screenshot attached. Can anyone suggest what might be the issue.

The error is @EnableInMemoryConnectionRepository cannot be resolved.
 UserIdSource cannot be resolved.

```
package controllers;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.social.connect.ConnectionFactoryLocator;
import org.springframework.social.connect.ConnectionRepository;
import org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController;
import org.springframework.social.facebook.config.annotation.EnableFacebook;

@EnableFacebook(appId="someAppId", appSecret="shhhhhh!!!")
@EnableInMemoryConnectionRepository
public class FacebookConfig {

    @Bean
    public ConnectController connectController(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator, ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {
        return new ConnectController(connectionFactoryLocator, connectionRepository);
    }

    @Bean
    public UserIdSource userIdSource() {
        return new UserIdSource() {
            @Override
            public String getUserId() {
                return "testuser";
            }
        };
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: I've also added spring-social-core 1.0.3 RELEASE jar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `spring-social-config .jar` file to your lib. This [link](http://maven.springframework.org/milestone/org/springframework/social/spring-social-config/1.1.0.M4/) will help you to download. Use spring-social-core-1.1.0.M4.jar instead of spring-social-core-1.0.0.Release.jar. Here, you can download from [here](http://maven.springframework.org/milestone/org/springframework/social/spring-social-core/1.1.0.M4/)

Comment: thanks, done "@EnableInMemoryConnectionRepository cannot be resolved" disappeared but 
" UserIdSource cannot be resolved." still exists

Comment: Thanks a lot brother, you saved me a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to fix this problem.

Clone the repo that site tell you to clone. 
Import the project as existing maven project. 
Then go to the .m2 folder and get all the jar file needed for this project